# Java Linux: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, linux, tcp

I am using Linux Mint 14 KDE. I've successfully created Java tcp server and client, server IP:port is 10.10.1.10:9900 and my client IP:port 10.10.1.10:9901. When i connect my client for the first time everything is OK. The client connects and sends some data and disconnects. When i try connecting the client with the server right after disconnecting i get the next Exception.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

If i wait more than 1 minute everything is OK. On other forums i read that after closing the socket there is a tcp time_wait that is 60 seconds (1 minute). After changing it to 0 everything worked (If someone want to change it just add this line **net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=0** in **/etc/sysctl.conf** and execute this line in your terminal as root **service networking restart**). The next day i tried to do one more test and i got the same exception. I checked if the time is still 0 (U can check it with writing this in command line **cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout** as root) and it was 0. I still had to wait 1 minute before reconnecting the client.

Can someone help me how to configure that way so i don't get this exception. Waiting 1 minute is too much for real-time application. I know i can do this with letting the OS dynamically assign port number that is free, but that is not what my application needs are.

Answer (score 1):

After creating your client socket, but before binding it or connecting to the remote server, you should call `Socket.setReuseAddress(true)` to enable reusing the client port.

Comment: I am using xSocket library i dont have that option. I build a non-blocking multi-threading tcp server and client. If u have experience with xSocket (downloaded it from http://xsocket.org/) it would be very helpful.

Comment: The point is to set the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag on the socket. I haven't worked with xsocket, but from skimming their documentation, it looks like you want to call `IConnection.setOption()` to set the `SO_REUSEADDR` option.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify a fixed client port, use zero. That way you will get a fresh one every time, or until you run out, which means you should be doing connection pooling at the client.